# Why does my game advance to one level too many?

Tags: javascript, game-development

I am trying to make my first game but am having trouble figuring out why the `gameState.nextLevel` screen is advancing me to level 5 when there are only 4 levels.

I think it may have to do with the `promptNextLevel` function which has a timeout function that sets `currentLevel++`.

I have tried adding `if` statements to prevent the function from running if `this.currentLevel = this.levels.length` but when I finish all 4 levels, I still get the popup from `gameState.nextLevel` that says "You completed level 4" then after 1 second it changes to "You completed level 5".

I tried adding an if statement that changes `gameState` to `gameOver` if `this.currentLevel = this.levels.length` but that doesn't do anything.

I have looked over the code for quite some time and can't figure it out. Please help!

I'm not sure what is relevant for someone to help, so I will copy the game.js file.

```js
const gameState = {
  paused: 0,
  running: 1,
  menu: 2,
  gameOver: 3,
  attempt: 4,
  nextLevel: 5,
}

export default class Game {

  constructor(gameWidth, gameHeight) {
    this.gameWidth = gameWidth;
    this.gameHeight = gameHeight;
    this.gameState = gameState.menu;
    this.paddle = new Paddle(this);

    this.ball = new Ball(this);
    this.gameObjects = [];
    this.lives = 3;
    this.lifeLost = false;
    this.bricks = [];
    this.levels = [Level1, Level2, Level3, Level4];
    this.currentLevel = 3;
    new InputHandler(this.paddle, this);
  }

  start() {
    //Start only from menu and nextLevel
    if (this.gameState !== gameState.menu &&
      this.gameState !== gameState.nextLevel
    ) return;

    this.bricks = buildLevel(this, this.levels[this.currentLevel]);

    this.ball.reset();
    this.gameObjects = [
      this.paddle,
      this.ball,
    ];

    this.gameState = gameState.running;
  }

  update(deltaTime) {
    //do not update if gameState is paused, menu, or gameOver
    if (this.gameState === gameState.paused ||
      this.gameState === gameState.menu ||
      this.gameState === gameState.gameOver ||
      this.gameState === gameState.nextLevel) {
      return
    }

    //Check for gameover       
    if (this.lives === 0) {
      this.gameState = gameState.gameOver
    };

    //if lifeLost then gameState attempt shows remaining lives for 3 sec
    if (this.lifeLost) {
      this.gameState = gameState.attempt;
      this.lifeLost = false;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.gameState = gameState.running;
      }, 3000);
      clearTimeout();
    }


    //update objects every frame game is running
    if (this.gameState === gameState.running) {
      [...this.gameObjects, ...this.bricks].forEach((object) => object.update(deltaTime));

      //filter out hit bricks
      this.bricks = this.bricks.filter(
        (object) => !object.markedForDeletion
      )
    }

    //progress to next level once all bricks hit

    if (!this.bricks.length) {
      if (this.currentLevel < this.levels.length) {
        this.gameState = gameState.nextLevel;
        this.promptNextLevel();
        return;
      }
    }
  }

  promptNextLevel() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.gameState === gameState.nextLevel) {
        this.currentLevel++;
        this.start();
      }
    }, 1000);
    clearTimeout();
  }

  draw(ctx) {
    //draw objects if game is running
    if (this.gameState === gameState.running)
      [...this.gameObjects, ...this.bricks].forEach((object) => object.draw(ctx));

    //sets the dialog and background for each gameState
    if (this.gameState === gameState.paused) {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(211, 211, 211, .5)';
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.gameWidth, this.gameHeight);
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.font = '30px Arial';
      ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.fillText('PAUSED', this.gameWidth / 2, this.gameHeight / 2);
    }

    if (this.gameState === gameState.menu) {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)';
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.gameWidth, this.gameHeight);
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.font = '30px Arial';
      ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.fillText('MENU', this.gameWidth / 2, this.gameHeight / 2 - 60);
      ctx.font = '18px Arial';
      ctx.fillText('Press SPACEBAR to start', this.gameWidth / 2, this.gameHeight / 2);
      ctx.fillText('Press H to view High Scores', this.gameWidth / 2, this.gameHeight / 2 + 30)
    }

    if (this.gameState === gameState.gameOver) {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)';
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.gameWidth, this.gameHeight);
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.font = '30px Arial';
      ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.fillText('GAME OVER', this.gameWidth / 2, this.gameHeight / 2 - 60);
      ctx.font = '18px Arial';
      ctx.fillText('Press ENTER for Main Menu', this.gameWidth / 2, this.gameHeight / 2);
    }

    if (this.gameState === gameState.attempt) {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)';
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.gameWidth, this.gameHeight);
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.font = '30px Arial';
      ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      if (this.lives > 1) {
        ctx.fillText(`You have ${this.lives} lives left`, this.gameWidth / 2, this.gameHeight / 2 - 60);
      } else {
        ctx.fillText(`You have ${this.lives} life left`, this.gameWidth / 2, this.gameHeight / 2 - 60);
      }
    }

    if (this.gameState === gameState.nextLevel) {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)';
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.gameWidth, this.gameHeight);
      ctx.fill();

      ctx.font = '30px Arial';
      ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.fillText(`You completed Level ${this.currentLevel + 1}`, this.gameWidth / 2, this.gameHeight / 2 - 60);
    }
  }

  togglePause() {
    if (this.gameState === gameState.running || this.gameState === gameState.paused) {
      if (this.gameState === gameState.paused) {
        this.gameState = gameState.running;
      } else this.gameState = gameState.paused;
    } else return;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is in your levels array? I think those need to be strings or if you defined it somewhere else, cause that is a data type that javascript doesn't recognize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your levels array contains four items, so the length is 4. However, the index (currentLevel) starts at 0. This means level 1 is index 0, level 2 is index 1, etc.

So, when you run this:

`if (this.currentLevel < this.levels.length )`

In level 4, you're actually checking if `3 < 4`, which of course is true. So, it prompts to the next level again.

Instead, you should check:

`if (this.currentLevel < this.levels.length - 1)`

Subtracting 1 from the length of the array will account for the fact that arrays in JavaScript start at 0 instead of 1.

Also, it would be a good idea to have another game state for winning the game, instead of running the same update loop after the last level is beat.

Comment: I updated the if statement like you said, but then the game wouldn't recognize that I completed the final level. I was able to get it to work by making a few modifications. I'll post them just in case it helps anyone in the future. It probably is not the best solution, but it works. See below

Comment: if (!this.bricks.length) {
           
            this.levelComplete = true;

            if (this.currentLevel < this.levels.length - 1 ) 
            {
                this.gameState = gameState.nextLevel;
                this.promptNextLevel();
                return;
            } 
            
        }

Comment: promptNextLevel() {
        setTimeout( () => {
                
            if (this.gameState === gameState.nextLevel) {

                this.currentLevel++;
                this.levelComplete = false;
                this.start(); 
            }
            
            
        }, 1000);
        clearTimeout();
    }

    gameWon() {

        setTimeout( () => {
            
                this.restart();
            
        }, 1000);
        clearTimeout();
        
    }

Comment: restart() {

        this.gameState = gameState.menu;
        this.lives = 3;
        this.levelComplete = false;
        this.currentLevel = 0;

    }

Comment: if (this.levelComplete) {
                this.gameState = gameState.winGame;
                this.gameWon();
                this.levelComplete = false;
            }

Comment: So now if the bricks are eliminated this.levelComplete = true, and if this.currentLevel < this.levels.length - 1, it runs this.promptNextLevel(). Otherwise this.gameState = gameState.winGame (which just displays a win message), and this.gameWon() is run which takes you back to the main menu.

Answer (score 0):

Game over needs to be

```
const gameOver = this.currentLevel === this.levels.length -1;
```

You must remember that arrays index from 0